# Passing null to java @WebMethod

Tags: java, web-services

This is my first time working with WS so maybe this will be a dumb question. I have generated my client with SoapUI and WebMethod looks like so

```
@WebResult(name = "result", targetNamespace = "http://xxx.wsdl", partName = "result")
@WebMethod(action = "xxx.wsdl/getBylWs")
public Kp2ParBylosOtUserArray getAWs(
        @WebParam(partName = "a", name = "a")
        String a,
        @XmlElement(nillable = true)
        @WebParam(partName = "b", name = "b")
        String b,
        @WebParam(partName = "c", name = "c")
        String c
);
```

b and c params can be null, in SoapUi this is easy nil="true" but how to pass null in java code?

Comment: If your public interface expects a null input by design, it is better to have an official overloaded method without that parameter. All your public parameters should be not-null.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `null` keyword instead of a value for the nullable parameter.

Comment: When i pass null I am getting this error `javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: Cannot write part A. RPC/Literal parts cannot be null. (WS-I BP R2211)
 at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:157)
 at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy29.getAWs(Unknown Source)`

Comment: Hmm... looks like you're missing the `nillable = true` decorator on the `c` parameter. Try adding that, like you did on `b`.

Comment: Oh forgot to mention that nillable=true does not work :)